# ruby threading output

Tags: ruby, multithreading, puts

I'm trying this example:

```
10.times do
  Thread.new do
    greeting_message = "Hello World ruby !"
    puts "#{greeting_message}
  end
end
```

I tried running this multiple times, and sometimes it `puts` once:

```
 Hello World ruby ! ruby basic_threadding_ruby.rb  0.05s user 0.04s system 97% cpu 0.096 total
```

other times its twice, sometimes its the full 10 times.

This inconsistency is making me confused. Is there a reason why `Hello World ruby !` is printed only once? I thought when you run a ruby script, it waits until all threads/processes are done before terminating and returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought when you run a ruby script, it waits until all threads/processes are done before terminating and returning?

Nope! From [the documentation for `Thread`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html):

> If we don't call `thr.join` before the main thread terminates, then all other threads including `thr` will be killed.

So you’ll need to join all of them:

```
threads = 10.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    puts 'Hello, Ruby!'
  end
end

threads.each &:join
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Sorry I should have read the docs before consulting here, but this is what I was missing! If I can ask one more question, `threads.each &:join` doesn't necessarily join them in the "right order"? They can still join in w/e random order they finished processing at correct ?

Comment: @user3358302: `threads.each &:join` joins them in order, but any number of them can have already finished processing by the time they’re joined (in which case `join` will return immediately), so there’s not a huge difference.